# How to run selenium tests as part of maven build phase using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, maven, selenium, selenium-rc

i wanna to realize this steps :
1-Start the tomcat server
2-Deploy the war
3-Start the selenium server

so i used this code in my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org   
/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
 v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tests.functional.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>functionalTestsSelenium</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>functionalTestsSelenium Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>functionalTestsSelenium</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>


        <!-- Start the tomcat server and Deploy the war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
                </container>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <!-- Start the selenium server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>
                        <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

So Now when i run the following command: mvn integration-test.

i can't see starting the tomcat and the selenium server, so i tried to test each one seperately via this commands :

```
mvn tomcat:run
mvn selenium:start-server
```

so the servers started well

Any idea please How to run selenium tests as part of maven build phase using Tomcat .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a sample project from the archetype here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/archetype.html

Then run:  **mvn clean install** :-)
Have a look at the pom in the module called basic-webapp-it 
HTH